# XCode Create NSManagedObject subclass will not generate classes for copied Entity

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my XCode project I copied an existing core data entity by copying the entity, pasting it, and renaming it.  I made a few changes to it and I selected Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass.  The only class that is generated is the entity that was copied.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that the class name is set for both entities?

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I didn't notice that the class name was the same.

Comment: If you submit an answer I will mark it as answered.